# Trying to create a report to show a % of active users who logged in each day

Tags: reporting

Trying to create a report to show the % of active users who logged in each day

I need to count (for adoption) % of Sales people who are using the system.......

I'm using Login Date - User Full Name + a poorly written % formula field

But still can't get the % field correct

We have **35** users on a pilot project so I need to see

10/08/2023  17 users logged in so 48%
11/08/2023  35 users logged in so 100%

You get the idea - I have been trying most of the day to get this sorted

Not sure my numbers are off because some users log in and out 3 or 4 times a day and others just log in once

Any help would be greatly appreciated

AH

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- Create a User Login report using the Users report type. This report will show the number of unique users logged in for a single day rather than the number of times a user logged in per day. You can also add a filter to this report to restrict the data to a single user per day.
- Add a formula field to the report that calculates the percentage of active users who logged in each day. To do this, you can use the following formula: **RowCount / PARENTGROUPVAL(RowCount, GRAND_SUMMARY, ACTIVE) * 100**. This formula will divide the number of users who logged in on a given day by the total number of active users and multiply by 100 to get the percentage. You can name this field as "% of Active Users Logged In"
- Add a chart to your report that shows the percentage of active users who logged in each day. You can choose any chart type that suits your needs, such as a line chart, a bar chart, or a pie chart. You can use the "Login Date" field as the X-axis and the "% of Active Users Logged In" field as the Y-axis. You can also customize the chart title, legend, colours, and other options.
- Save and run your report. You should see a report that shows the percentage of active users who logged in each day in Salesforce.

Screenshots:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed response I will give this a go when I'm back in the office